# Enter Math or Chemistry Equations In Text box/Text Area In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to enter mathematics or chemistry or some other subject data, which have equations to Text Box/Test Area.

How can I write them properly in Text Box and save to DB (SQL)?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your expected input?

Comment: (A) O2, CH4 (B) H2, O2 (C) N2, CO2 (D) Na, CO.                                                                                      2/4 should be prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out LaTeX or MathJax, which are specialized in writing scientific formulas and their output is a textual definition of the formula which can then be normally stored as any other text in DB.

However, without a [specialized WYSIWYG editor](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/List-of-web-based-math-editors) you will not be able to do this if you want the user editing the `input` to actually not write code and create the equations/formulas visually.